# how to securely pass sensitive information from client side (browser) to a service?

Tags: ajax, owasp, secure-coding

User enters a sensitive information on a HTML textfield, and this information need to be passed to a third party service (over https, possible ajax call) for tokenization. What are the best practices to ensure this information is handled securely (without leaving any trace of this sensitive information at the client side) at the client side?

Comment: Make sure to use HTTPS, use an API key or some other authorization method on the service. But you cannot guarantee what the client does on their machine -- so if they cache form fields, etc. you will have no control over that.

Comment: API key (or authorization credentials) will be visible on the client side - is there a secure way of handling this?

Comment: I would start here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Service_Security_Cheat_Sheet